# Moving an image on Scroll using useEffect not Working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, parallax

Currently I'm trying to create a parallax effect using useEffect to manipulate my DOM elements. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Where the image is vertically fixed in the middle of the screen and can move horizontally and the first text moves upward vertically and the second text comes from below the image horizontally from left to right. But right now my image is not moving from side to side and the text in my second window is not moving how I want it to.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedscroll-n952b?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      let img = document.getElementById("moveLeft");
      let text = document.getElementById("moveUp");
      let text2 = document.getElementById("text2");

      img.style.left = value * 0.5 + "px";
      text.style.marginTop = "-" + value * 0.5 + "px";
      text2.style.left = value * 1 + "px";
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div class="inflow">
          <div class="positioner">
            <div class="fixed">
              <div
                id="moveUp"
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  color: "#fff",
                  fontSize: "40px"
                }}
              >
                VANATAU
              </div>
              <div id="moveLeft">
                <img
                  alt="passport"
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="App2">
        <div className="half">
          <div className="text2" id="text2">
            MINIMUM INVESTMENT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="App2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `property` on `position: static` element (div).
You should either add `position: absolute` to `#moveLeft` or use `translateX`:

```
img.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 0.5}px)`
```

Comment: Can you try making this change in the sandbox. Since I tried to implement your changes and it's still not working

Comment: I am not sure what's the expected situation [https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedscroll-forked-3pwy6?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedscroll-forked-3pwy6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Alright I just added a minus in `translateX(-${value * 0.5}px)` and the image moved towards the left. But now for the second half of my question I still want my text of the second window to be moved from left to right while the text stays in the middle vertically

Comment: I tried out a little bit more and this is what I somewhat want. https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-gates-h99z3?file=/src/styles.css . The only problem here is I cant hide my left text behind my .half css property even after trying a z-index

Comment: That's because `.half` box is under the text, so there's nothing to hide the text. 
[https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fire-yriyu?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fire-yriyu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes thats how I want it, to be hidden under my .half since I want my text2 to only be visible after my text1 is out of the window